# How change icon on a button dynamically with JavaScript after 2 seconds when clicked?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, clipboard.js

The main purpose of my script is to announce that the copy of the text has been successfully completed.

When I click on the button, the first icon change was ok, as is the toast display, and the text is correctly copied with the framework **clipboard.js**.

```
<button 
   class="btn btn-outline-success"
   id="url-rss" data-clipboard-text="Texte à copier">
      <i class="fa-regular fa-clipboard" id="icon"></i>
</button>
```

when i click on the button, 2 secondes after, I want the script change the button again to `fa-circle-check` to `fa-clipboard`.

I use **clipboard.js**, **Bootstrap 5 (bundle)** & **Font Awesome**.

This is my script :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Load of Clipboard.js
    let clipboard = new ClipboardJS('#url-rss')

    // Variable for the Toast with Bootstrap 5
    let toastCopie = new bootstrap.Toast(document.querySelector('#copieToast'), {
        animation: true,
        delay: 2500
    });

    // We listen #url-rss on click
    document.querySelector('#url-rss').addEventListener('click', async function() {
        // If Click on the <button> do a Toast()
        toastCopie.show()

        let iconElement = document.querySelector('#icon')

        // Change of the icon, first round
        iconElement.classList.remove('fa-clipboard')
        iconElement.classList.add('fa-circle-check')

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

        // Chnage of the icon, second round
        iconElement.classList.remove('fa-circle-check');
        iconElement.classList.add('fa-clipboard');
    })
});
```

I have copy an example of my [script on codepen](https://codepen.io/Machou/pen/oNVgwOY?editors=1011=) if anyone want try.

I have try with this too :

```js
        setTimeout(function() {
            iconElement.classList.remove('fa-circle-check');
            iconElement.classList.add('fa-clipboard');
        }, 2000);
```

But after various attempts and research, my JavaScript skills aren't advanced enough for me to solve this problem on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Machou.
you tried below code but maybe it didn't work correctly, right?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    iconElement.classList.remove('fa-circle-check');
    iconElement.classList.add('fa-clipboard');
}, 2000);
```

the main reason is that iconElement in above example is not correct, because it doesn't refer it's origin form after 2 seconds.

this will work fine if you correct your code like this.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   let iconElement = document.querySelector('#icon');   
   iconElement.classList.remove('fa-circle-check');
   iconElement.classList.add('fa-clipboard');
}, 2000);
```

iconElement must be redelcared in this scope.
because if you change classname of svg element that change it's shape, past element does not exist anymore.

I tested this code in you codepen snippet.
If you have any other javascript tacklings, please dm me. (It's my pleasure)

Comment: Some solutions are so simple that they become complicated :P Thanks for your answer :)